# Page break with DOCX4J

Tags: java, docx4j

I need to add a table at the end of the document and the table to should start in a separate page. Can anyone help? Currently I am able to add the table at the end of the content of the existing docx file. I need to know how I can introduce a page break and start the the table at the end of the exist document in a separate page with docx4J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple page break, unless you need different page size or headers/footers (in which case use a next page section break).

For a simple page break, the XML you need is:

```
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:br w:type="page"/>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

Corresponding Java:

```
    // Create object for p
    P p2 = wmlObjectFactory.createP(); 
    body.getContent().add( p2); 
        // Create object for r
        R r = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p2.getContent().add( r); 
            // Create object for br
            Br br = wmlObjectFactory.createBr(); 
            r.getContent().add( br); 
                br.setType(org.docx4j.wml.STBrType.PAGE);
```

You can generate this code from a suitable sample docx (created in Word) using the Helper addin for Word, or the Docx4j Webapp.

Comment: As an alternate approach as because I needed the page at the very end of the original document, I created a separate template document and added that or rather merged that with the actual document after completing required alterations in the appended (appended or new template doc) document.